# How to make other apps use your custom font for a language whose font is not present on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, fonts, keyboard

I'm planning to create a keyboard in iOS for a language script which has unicode block allocated to it but neither android nor iOS has it's font. I'll get the font made by someone but will other apps like WhatsApp use that font instead of showing boxes

Comment: no, you cannot install fonts at the OS level for other apps to use, only your own app that I know of.

Comment: @Scriptable then how does this app work? https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fonts/id1454061614

Comment: you must be able to install the font in the keyboard extension then and use it that way globally. I think you also just answered your own question